# jquery min and maxlength validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want `minlength=8` and `maxlength=14`, how can I achieve this validation.

html:

```
<input type="text" name="354" id="field">
```

jQuery:

```
$("input[name=354]").keypress(function(e){
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
$("#errmsg").html("Digits only").show().fadeOut("slow");
return false;
}
});
```

Comment: What do your min and maxlength refer to?  All you have here is a keypress event which will fire on each individual key press.  If you are trying to validate the field overall, making sure there are 8-14 'digits' in the field then you'll need to validate on submission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use HTML5 attributes `minlength` and `maxlength` to manage input text length. But if you want to use JQuery to do this work, see this example

```js
var minLength = 3;
var maxLength = 10;

$("input").on("keydown keyup change", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length < minLength)
        $("span").text("Text is short");
    else if (value.length > maxLength)
        $("span").text("Text is long");
    else
        $("span").text("Text is valid");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 9):

Now with HTML5 you can use the properties `minlength` and `maxlength`.

```html
<input type="text" minlength="8" maxlength="14" name="354" id="field">
```

Comment: How can I achieve this using jquery?